# prevent image uploading if oversize

Tags: javascript, angularjs, npm

I need to prevent a image uploading if over a set size, my error works and shows if image is over set size but the image still uploads.
I am using [angular-base64-upload](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-base64-upload).

I do not know why image still displays when its over the limet, any idea why ?

thanks

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="UpLoadImage">

<div ng-repeat="step in stepsModel">
    <img class="thumb" ng-src="{{step}}"/>
</div>

<label for="file">Add Creative</label>

<form name="form">
    <input type='file' ng-model='files' name='files' multiple accept='image/*, .zip' maxsize='50' onload='onLoad'
           ng-model-instant onchange='angular.element(this).scope().imageUpload(this)' required
           base-sixty-four-input>
    <span ng-show='form.files.$error.maxsize'>Files must not exceed 50 KB</span>
</form>
```

**App.js**

```
angular.module('myApp', ['naif.base64'])
.controller('UpLoadImage', function ($scope, $http, $window, $rootScope) {

    $scope.imageUpload = function (element) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = $scope.imageIsLoaded;
        reader.readAsDataURL(element.files[0]);
    };

    $scope.imageIsLoaded = function (e) {
        $scope.$apply(function () {
            $scope.stepsModel.push(e.target.result);
        });

        $scope.onLoad = function (e, reader, file, fileList, fileOjects, fileObj) {
            alert('image uploaded');
        };
    };

    $scope.stepsModel = [];
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your `input` is listening for an `onchange` event to do the uploading—nothing prevents this change event from proceeding.

`form.files.$error.maxsize` will return `true` or `false`, so use that boolean to drive whether or not the change event proceeds with the upload attempt.

I suggest moving your upload logic into your controller.

Also, if you use `ng-change`, you could shorten your reference to your controller method:

`ng-change="imageUpload(this, form.files.$error.maxsize)"`

If you expand your `imageUpload` method to take a second argument, you can check if the image is too big to proceed:

```
$scope.imageUpload = function (element, maxSizeError) {

    if(maxSizeError) { 
        // handle error logic
     } else {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = $scope.imageIsLoaded;
        reader.readAsDataURL(element.files[0]);
     }
};
```